# $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}...=\frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

On a problem book solution I was faced with the following step:

> $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}...=\frac{1}{n}$$

I identified $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}...$ as a geometric series so the sum would be $\frac{1}{1-r}$ so that $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{n}$. I do not understand what I am doing worng.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not a whole geometric series. There is a first term of $1$ before the $\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ term. Add that in, the $1$s on both sides cancel out to get the equation you want.

Comment: It's a geometric series starting at $k=1$ not $k=0$

Comment: So the sum of $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = \frac 1{1-r}=1+\frac 1n$ so $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r^k = ( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k ) - r^0 = ....????....$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the formula
$$
1+x+x^2+x^3+\dotsb=\frac{1}{1-x}\quad (|x|<1)\quad (\star)
$$
where $x=\frac{1}{n+1}$. The problem is that your desired sum omits the initial term of $1$ in $(\star)$. Hence subtract $1$ from your sum, $1+n^{-1}$, to get the right result.

Answer (score 3):

The geometric sequence does not start with $1$.

The general form is $$ a + ar + ar^2 + ... = \frac {a}{1-r}$$ for $|r|<1$

Therefor the sum

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}...=\frac{1}{n}$$

is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that $a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots = \dfrac{a}{1-r}$ for $|r|\lt 1$

then here you have $a= \dfrac1{n+1}$ and $r=  \dfrac1{n+1}$

so the sum is $\dfrac{\frac1{n+1}}{{1-\frac1{n+1}}}=\dfrac{1}{n+1-1}=\dfrac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

**How I recommend approaching these problems**:

Use the fact that if $|x| < 1$, 
$$1 + x + x^2 + \cdots = \dfrac{1}{1-x}\text{.} \tag{*}$$

Then, factor to rewrite the problem so that it is in terms of the equation (*).

---

Observe that if I factor out $\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ that

$$\dfrac{1}{n+1} + \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \cdots = \dfrac{1}{n+1}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\cdots \right)\text{.}\tag{A}$$

The sum
$$1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \cdots = \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}} = \dfrac{1}{(n+1-1)/(n+1)} = \dfrac{n+1}{n}\tag{B}$$
as long as $$\left|\dfrac{1}{n+1} \right| < 1 \implies |n+1| > 1 \implies n+1 > 1 \text{ and } -(n+1) < -1 \implies n > 0\text{.}$$
Thus, as long as $n > 0$, combine (A) and (B) to get
$$\dfrac{1}{n+1} \cdot \dfrac{n+1}{n} = \dfrac{1}{n}$$
as desired.

Please be sure to note that **this is only true when $n > 0$**. I have seen mistakes in the past when people ignore assumptions made when summing infinite geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

> I identified 1n+1+1(n+1)2... as a geometric series so the sum would be 11−r so that 11−1n+1=1+1n. I do not understand what I am doing worng.

Take a look at your indexes.

A) You have $\frac 1{1+n} + (\frac 1{n+1})^2 + ..... = \sum_{k= 1}^{\infty} (\frac 1{1+n})^k$

B) So you did: Let $r = \frac 1{n+1}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}( \frac 1{1+n})^k =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k=\frac 1{1-r} = 1 + \frac 1n$.

Take a closer look do you see the difference between $\sum_{k= 1}^{\infty} (\frac 1{1+n})^k$ in A) and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac 1{1+n})^k$ in B)?

....

Now $\sum_{k= 1}^{\infty} \frac 1{1+n}^k = [\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac 1{1+n})^k] - (\frac 1{n+1})^0 = ....???....$